# After checking if device supports flashlight, can't put boolean value inside if statement

Tags: java, android, android-package-managers, flashlight

I checked if device supports flash and I made an if statement, then I am getting an error. Does anyone know solution for this? It is saying that `hasFlash` is an unknown class.

```
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.widget.ImageButton;


import static android.content.DialogInterface.*;

public class Flashlight extends AppCompatActivity {
private CameraManager cm;
private ImageButton flashlightButton;
private boolean flashlightOnOrOff;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flashlight);
    flashlightButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flashOnOffButton);
    flashlightOnOrOff = false;
}

//Error if device does not have flashlight
boolean hasFlash = this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
//This is where i get the error
if(hasFlash==false)

{
    AlertDialog dialo = new AlertDialog.Builder(Flashlight.this).create();
    dialo.setTitle("Error");
    dialo.setMessage("Sorry your device does not have flashlight");
    dialo.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
            finish();
        }
    });
    dialo.show();


}




//What flashlight does on Stop
@Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
}

//What flashlight does on Pause
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
}

//What flashlight does on Resume
@Override
protected void onPostResume() {
    super.onPostResume();
}
```

}

Comment: what is the error?

Comment: `hasFlash == false` can be simplified to `!hasFlash`

Comment: Has multible erros on the same line : 1. Unexpected token 2.Unknown class `hasFlash 3. Indentifie expected

Comment: Hmm. . . looks like you've made a mistake elsewhere in the code. You should post the entire file, the error is likely outside the snippet of code currently in your question.

Comment: Posted the entire file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code in question isn't in a function. Did you mean to put that in your onCreate? If so, your closing brace is in the wrong place:

```
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_flashlight);
    flashlightButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.flashOnOffButton);
    flashlightOnOrOff = false; 
} // REMOVE THIS 

//Error if device does not have flashlight 
    boolean hasFlash = this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
    if(hasFlash==false)
    {
        AlertDialog dialo = new AlertDialog.Builder(Flashlight.this).create();
        dialo.setTitle("Error");
        dialo.setMessage("Sorry your device does not have flashlight");
        dialo.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                finish();
            }
        });
        dialo.show();
    }
} // THIS IS WHERE YOUR ONCREATE CLOSING BRACE GOES
```

Comment: This fixed my problem, thanks alot!

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
hasFlash = getApplicationContext().getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);

if (!hasFlash) {    
// device doesn't support flash    
// Show alert message and close the application  

    AlertDialog alert = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this).create();    
    alert.setTitle("Error");    
    alert.setMessage("Sorry, your device doesn't support flash light!");  

    alert.setButton("OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {    
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

        // closing the application    
        finish();    
    }

    });

    alert.show();    
    return;

}
```

Comment: How does this solve the problem?

Answer (score -1):

Put following permission on AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" />
```

Put following imports on top of your MainActivity.java

```
package com.stackoverflow.myapplication;

import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import static android.content.DialogInterface.BUTTON_POSITIVE;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        boolean hasFlash = this.getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH);
        AlertDialog dlg = new AlertDialog.Builder(this).create();
        if (hasFlash) {
            dlg.setTitle("Done");
            dlg.setMessage("Your device does have flashlight");
        }
        else {
            dlg.setTitle("Error!");
            dlg.setMessage("Sorry your device does not have flashlight!");
        }

        dlg.setButton(BUTTON_POSITIVE, "OK", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialogInterface, int i) {
                //finish();
            }
        });
    dlg.show();
    }

}
```

For more details look at [here](http://www.mkyong.com/android/how-to-turn-onoff-camera-ledflashlight-in-android/)

Comment: Thank you for the answer, but i already have those 2 in AndroidManifest.

Comment: add import statement above MainActivity.java before use the functions.

Comment: The error clearly isn't with permissions or an import.

Comment: You put your code outside of onCreate function.